# How to efficiently analyze simulation results with various degrees of freedoms?

Tags: charts, analysis

I have been doing a lot of application testing, trying different libraries, threading ratios, operation distributions, etc... I want to be able to quickly generate graphs from my run data.

The data is outputted to a tab separated file that is conceptually divided into a left half and a right half. Each row is a separate execution configuration.

The left half is various configuration parameters and the right half is a series of execution time. (For example we may run a configuration 20 times to insure an even average)

I want to quickly be able to plot graphs of this data and/or calculate values such as standard deviation.

For example I would specify a column in the right half to be used as the X-axis, and the rest of the right half columns would be used to identify the execution config used to generate the line. The Y-axis will always be execution time (or normalized performance)

For example the left hand side could be

```
| Threads | Elements | AlgorithmA | AlgorithmB |
|---------+----------+------------+------------|
|       1 |      100 | t1a        | t1b        |
|       2 |      100 | t1a        | t1b        |
|       3 |      100 | t1a        | t1b        |
|       1 |   100000 | t1a        | t1b        |
|       2 |   100000 | t1a        | t1b        |
|       3 |   100000 | t1a        | t1b        |
|---------+----------+------------+------------|
|       1 |      100 | t2a        | t1b        |
|       2 |      100 | t2a        | t1b        |
|       3 |      100 | t2a        | t1b        |
|       1 |   100000 | t2a        | t1b        |
|       2 |   100000 | t2a        | t1b        |
|       3 |   100000 | t2a        | t1b        |
|---------+----------+------------+------------|
|       1 |      100 | t2a        | t2b        |
|       2 |      100 | t2a        | t2b        |
|       3 |      100 | t2a        | t2b        |
|       1 |   100000 | t2a        | t2b        |
|       2 |   100000 | t2a        | t2b        |
|       3 |   100000 | t2a        | t2b        |
|---------+----------+------------+------------|
|       1 |      100 | t1a        | t2b        |
|       2 |      100 | t1a        | t2b        |
|       3 |      100 | t1a        | t2b        |
|       1 |   100000 | t1a        | t2b        |
|       2 |   100000 | t1a        | t2b        |
|       3 |   100000 | t1a        | t2b        |
|---------+----------+------------+------------|
```

If the X-axis would be Threads then there would be 8 lines each line with 3 data points, then to filter to only one element size.
If the X-axis was elements then there would be 16 lines, each line with 2 data points, then I would filter it to only one thread level.

My google fu has failed me at finding one I like, maybe I am searching the wrong keywords...so my questions is what application can you recommend to solve my problem and make my days less repetitive.

Comment: Do you have any software preferences for this? Excel Pivot Tables/Charts seem like a natural fit for your data exploration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do pretty much all of this in Python with [IPython](http://ipython.org/), [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org) and [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/), with some [`statsmodels`](http://statsmodels.sf.net/) thrown in for good measure. There are some other dependencies, like [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org), so read the docs.

I highly recommend reading [Python For Data Analysis](http://oreilly.com/shop/product/0636920023784.html) as it walks you through all the packages I mentioned and more, although basic knowledge of Python is assumed.

Comment: Sorry Thought I did upvote it